# simplify the environment newtheorem

Tags: environments, newtheorem

Is there a way to simplify the following newtheorem environment

```
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

instead of using it as follows

```
\begin{definiton}[xxx]
   yyy
\end{definiton}
```

is it possible to use it as follows

```
\definiton[xxx]{
   yyy
 }
```

Comment: is it possible to shorten an environment by getting rid of begin and end as in my example above?

Comment: most latex editors will let you add \begin{definition} \end{definition} with just three or four keystrokes, there really isn't any advantage in the command form. I deleted my first comment after your edit.

Comment: The environment for is *much* easier to manage: the `\begin` and `\end` tags are much more prominent than just `\definition{` and `}` (particularly for the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a command that wraps its argument in your definition environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definitionenv}[theorem]{Definition}
\NewDocumentCommand{\definition}{o m}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \begin{definitionenv}
            #2
        \end{definitionenv}%
    }{%
        \begin{definitionenv}[#1]
            #2
        \end{definitionenv}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{definitionenv}
    yyy
\end{definitionenv}

\begin{definitionenv}[xxx]
    yyy
\end{definitionenv}

\definition{
    yyy
}

\definition[xxx]{
    yyy
}
\end{document}
```

[image]